# find space guid by account name, organisation name and space name

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

My end goal is to return a space guid based on the following inputs:

- user account name, e.g. `me`
- organization name, e.g. `me@email.com`
- space name, e.g. `dev`

Cloud Foundry has these APIs for spaces and organizations, and I'm able to make these calls no problem:

```
GET /v2/organizations?q:name=MY_ORGANIZATION_NAME
GET /v2/spaces?q:name=MY_SPACE_NAME
```

There is also a Cloud Foundry API for users:

```
 GET /v2/user?q:name=MY_USER_NAME
```

However, when I try to make the above call, I get:

```
403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://api.ng.bluemix.net/v2/users?q:name=MY_USER_NAME
```

For each of the calls, I am setting the header `authorization: X Y` value to the `access_token` and `token_type` returned from:

```
https://login.ng.bluemix.net/UAALoginServerWAR/oauth/token
```

Is there another way that I can achieve my end goal to retrieve the space guid?

Comment: Why do you need user info? When making calls as a user you only see info to which you have access. Getting a space guid should not require any account info.

Comment: Ah, ok.  Are org names globally unique? My concern was that if I just filter on org name and space name I may return multiple results if org names are not globally unique.

Comment: I believe they are but cannot say definitively

Comment: You are right.  I just tried to create a duplicate org and it failed.  Filtering by org name and space name will suffice.  Many thanks!

Comment: @JoshGhiloni if you would like to add your comments as an answer, I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortunately for your situation, the account apis are not necessary. Organization names are globally unique, so filtering on that info before getting space guids should suffice.